# Is it possible to make round corners for child Panes settings rules only to parent Pane in JavaFX?

Tags: java, css, javafx

I have the following fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<StackPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane maxHeight="200.0" maxWidth="200.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
         <children>
            <VBox style="-fx-border-radius: 10; -fx-border-color: black; -fx-border-width: 1;" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
               <children>
                  <Pane maxWidth="200.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: red;" />
                  <Pane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: cyan;" />
                  <Pane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: green;" />
               </children>
            </VBox>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</StackPane>
```

And this is the result:
[image]

VBox has the following css rule:

```
-fx-border-radius: 10; 
-fx-border-color: black; 
-fx-border-width: 1;
```

The problem is that child corners (total 4 corners) are outside parent - I mean that 4 child corners are not round according to parent radius. Is it possible to fix it without setting rules to child panes? If yes, then how? I am asking it because in real application I have in parent many different children and order of these children can change and I don't want to control child radius.

Comment: The easiest solution is to simply round the child node corners.

Comment: You have a history of creating problems where there should be none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use shape clipping with a round rectangle. Bind its coordinates and dimensions to the source pane and it should work flawlessly.

```
import javafx.scene.shape.*;

VBox box = ...;
Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
r.widthProperty().bind(box.widthProperty());
r.heightProperty().bind(box.heightProperty());
r.setArcWidth(10);
r.setArcHeight(10);

box.setClip(r);
```

Comment: Could you explain how to make shape clipping?

Answer (score 0):

a bit late as I can see, but you could achieve this without having to do any extra work. 
You only have to use css :
In your css file, simply select the AnchorPanes using css. For an instance, let's think that your root's id is #rootPane, 
you can use #rootPane to style the rest of the Anchor Panes using the following way,

```
#rootPane AnchorPane{
    -fx-background-radius:200; /* a value of your preference*/
}
```

will get exactly what you want.
The output is here : 
[The Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7rcZ.png)

I've added colours to the Anchor Panes externally, just for visual purposes